# How to change the height of the view based on width

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints, size-classes

My views width will change according to the device width but I want to change the height according to that I don't want that to be static.

I couldn't find any constraint that can take care of this.

I heard aspect ratio can do this. But I tried It doesn't seem to work.

How it is generally achieved?

Comment: Please add your content to show us what actually your UI looked like. Add your approach and finally your expected output.

Comment: How do you want the height to change? Do you want it to be proportional to the whole screen? Do you want it to be in a specific ratio to the width?

Comment: @Rikh - Can you please explain me how to do both of this ? cuz for some view I want the former while for the other view I want the later one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use concept of aspect ratio with AutoLayout to update your view with respect to height & width. Use multiplier to update aspect ratio. Here are snap of aspect ration assignment and how to update it's multiplier

[image]
[image]

**Logic of Multiplier**:

1:1 = Height and width of your image will remain same

2:1 = Your width or height is 2x with respect to each other and create a rectangle. Here Height will be 2x or width will be 2x, it depends upon first item and second item in constraint.

**Logic of Priority**:
Priority assigns, priority to specific constraint when it conflicts with another constraint of same view. e.g. if you have set a view with 1:1 aspect ratio, with 100 height & 100 width and centred in Main View. Now you also assign Left (margin)/Leading constraint as fix value like 200. In that case for different size of screen width, Centred alignment and/or Leading alignment and/or aspect ration will conflict each other. At this point you need to update priority between 0-1000, according to your requirement for adjustment of design.

Share me your design, I will give your exact logic, how to use this concept

Comment: what does that multiplier 1:1 mean and can you brief me about other things as well like Relation .. what are other relations available and which scenario it can be used ? what is the priority,constant,identifier,placeholder,installed etc...

Comment: Please help me understand I will appreciate by upvoting your posts once 1 reach more than 15 points... hope you'll help me out

Comment: Can you please explain me the logic of constant,relation,identifier,placeholder and installed as well ?

Comment: I think you should go through this: http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/   as it's huge concept.

Comment: Upvoters, please add your comment for upvote, so I can compensate your upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Try with following easy way..

1) Give `Leading` and `Trailing` **Constraint** like below image.

[image]

2) Now set `Top` or `Bottom` or Other **Constraint** as per your design. For me i have settled `Vertically Center`.

[image]

3) Now set `Height` of `UIView` as per your `Ratio` which you want in design and after selecting that `view` just `Drag and Drop` on same `view` and select `Aspect Ratio`. `XCode` will automatically get `Ratio Constraint`. For ref. see below image.

[image]

Comment: I am confused with ratio constraint with width and height ... if I want the height to vary then do I have to choose height and aspect ratio .. so that height willl change according to the varying width ... clarify me the relation plz

Comment: Thanks for the step by step image... I like it

Comment: **Constrain to Margins** how does it affect the leading,trailing,top and bottom ? please explain..

Comment: likewise in the alignment constraints..there are so many things like baselines,horizontal centers,vertical centers etc... if you could explain me a bit... It'd be helpful for me

Comment: I will definetly appreciate your help by upvoting ur posts... once I reach more than 15 .. hope you will help me

Comment: Ratio : For example currently you need square view and you are having iphone 4 (320 * 480). Now you need to set leading and trailing 10,10 remain  width of 300. For square now you need height also 300. Set height to 300 and set aspect ratio it will calculate automatically for iphone6, 6 plus and 5.

Comment: so you mean to say I have to tick **width** as 300 and **height** as 300 and tick **Aspect ratio** as well .... but if I add 300 as a width then it won't get fixed huh ? won't there be any conflict cuz ... leading edge has to be 10,trailing edge has to be 10 and if the screen is little wider ... than 320 ... won't it break ?